# URL Scheme (imdb:///, linkedin://) not launching app in Android device

Tags: android, linkedin-api, imdb

I have tested this scheme URL (`imdb:///`, `linkedin://`) app home page can't launching in Android device. but both home page/specified page app scheme URL works fine in iOS.

(`imdb:///title/tt1931435/`, `linkedin://profile/{id}`) this specified app page launch perfectly in Android device.

I can't understand why this different in scheme URL?

Appreciate your inputs on how to resolve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS you directly register your app to open for scheme's. When you do that, whatever you give after imdb://, the app opens. You can open it with either imdb:// or imdb://something

But in Android the behavior is different. You don't simply register for the scheme, you register for the complete path or path prefix or even use regex. When imdb:///title/tt1931435/ opens the IMDB app, simple imdb:// may not open the app directly.

The developers behind IMDB app probably wanted the app to be open only from the movie screens but not from the main screen.

**Edit:**
After your comment I looked up `AndroidManifest.xml` files of both Facebook and IMDB and the result is the below

IntentFilter in IMDB application:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="imdb" android:host="" android:pathPattern="/title/tt.*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

IntentFilter in Facebook application:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="fb" />
        </intent-filter>
```

In Facebook, there is only "fb" and this means all the url's that starts with fb:// will open the app. But in IMDB, they provided `android:pathPattern`, which means only the URL's that fit that pattern will open the app.

Comment: I have another doubt (fb://) open the app directly in android device. How is it possible?

Comment: The developer can decide if something:// will open the app or not. In Android you can decide exactly what will open or not. Facebook let the app open with fb:// but imdb not.

Comment: I provided an example